# Calcular el largo de un arreglo en pseint

Tags: array, pseint, pseudocódigo

Tengo un arreglo llamado banco que almacena palabras y tiene un maximo de 2000
Quiero crear una funcion que me permita ingresar una cantidad de palabras y a partir de las palabras en el arreglo generar una palabra aleatoria solo si la cantidad de palabras ingresada es menor o igual a las palabras que hay en el arreglo.
Lo siguiente es parte de mi codigo:

```
Funcion textoAleatorio<-generarTextoAleatorio(cantPalabras,banco2)
    indice<-1
    Para u<-1 Hasta 2000 Con Paso 1 Hacer
        Mientras banco2[u] <> "" Hacer
            indice<- indice+1
        FinMientras
    FinPara
    Si indice >= cantPalabras Entonces
        Para x<-1 Hasta cantPalabras Hacer
            Escribir "la palabra es:"
            textoAleatorio<-textoAleatorio + "" + banco2[x]
        FinPara
    SiNo
        textoAleatorio<-"No hay suficientes palabras para generar ese texto"
    FinSi
FinFuncion
```

Con la variable indice estoy intentando contar cuantas palabras hay en el arreglo pero por alguna razon no logro que aumente.